# Passing a defined pom.xml property to @jboss.entity-command in java class

Tags: java, properties, maven-2, maven-profiles, xdoclet

I have a project with several entity beans and at some point I have

```
@jboss.entity-command name="informix-serial"
```

In DEV, my database is MySql but in PRD I have Informix. What I want is to pass some property defined in my pom.xml, associated with a profile when I compile the project.

I've tried this:

In pom.xml

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
      <jboss.entity.command>mysql-get-generated-keys</jboss.entity.command>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>prd</id>
    <properties>
      <jboss.entity.command>informix-serial</jboss.entity.command>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

and in the beans:

```
@jboss.entity-command name="${jboss.entity.command}"
```

The problem is, obviously, that the variable  ${jboss.entity.command} is not being resolved to the value.

Any light on the subject will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
ML

Comment: Done! I used filtering resources with maven.